# How to advance adapter to use addItem function in Android?

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem. I can't modify some code to advance it for something functionallity.

Here the code:

```
final Item[] items = {
                new Item("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add, 7),
                new Item("Facebook", resId, 99),
            };

            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
                android.R.id.text1,
                items){
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        //User super class to create the View
                        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                        //Put the image on the TextView
                        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(items[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);

                        //Add margin between image and text (support various screen densities)
                        int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                        tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

                        return v;
                    }
                };
```

This code must create a menu with icons from left side and need one class, here:

```
public class Item {
    public final String text;
    public final int icon;
    public final int act;

    public Item(String text, Integer icon, Integer act) {
        this.text = text;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.act = act;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

    public int getAct() {
        return act;
    }

}
```

This class Item I wanna modify to add items easy, for example, `Item.addItem(str,int,int)`

How to do that?

Comment: use an ArrayList instead of an array

Comment: Please, can you explain how to do that? I need replace this code:
 `final Item[] items = {
 new Item("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add, 7),
 new Item("Facebook", resId, 99),
 };
 
 with like this:
`Item items = new Item();
 for(int i; i<3; i++)
 {
 items.add(tra-ta-ta);
 }`

Comment: the NeronT answer looks good to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

items.add(new Item(str,int,int));
```

Comment: I receive the error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String> to List<Item>`. I want just create copy of class Item and in cycle add items. Thank you!

Comment: wrote String instead of Item, think before copy&pasting code please. Fixed in the answer now.

Comment: In code that I wrote in 1st post give to me an error: `tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(items[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);` Error: `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<Item>`.

Comment: `tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(items.get(position).icon, 0, 0, 0);`  But it seems that you will get stuck in every single step of your program, you should start with a tutorial (for plain java).

Comment: Oh MAN, you save my time and you right, I need a tutorial, because Im not a java developer bu Web Dev, and I just try myself in Java. THANK YOU so much! You help to solve my 2 days task! Im happy))